# Complexity of iterating over two loops to find results

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

I have an array key_words = [abc, ugh, yut, asd]
I have another array of words = [wer, ray, ugh, ghjgj, asa, dog, rte, yut, top, asd.........]

I need to find the position of key_words in the words.

the question is : should I iterate over key_words and search for them in words? or the other way around?

My first instinct is that the outer loop should be on key_words and then the internal loop should be on words so that I can exit the loop on words when a match is found.

However, in both the cases, the complexity is m*n , m being the length of words and n being the length of key words.

What should be done or are both the same cases?
Please do not tell me about tries or another faster method to search. `My query is does the order of the loops effect the complexity and can this be handled?`

Comment: Well i think your approach is right. If you dont wanna use any methods and want to loop through the array elements. Yes you would have to go for the O(mn) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

How about one pass to create an array like:

```
keyArray = ['wer' => 1, 'abg' => 2, 'saf' => 3 ]
```

And then you can just use indexes which are based on a hash implementation in most languages so you'd be much closer to n ( 2n? )

```
index = keyArray['wer'];
```

Comment: My question is a simplified version of the actual situation. Generating this hash and subsequent access seems to be the best approach but u wanted to know what the complexity of my approach was

Answer (score 0):

In terms of theoretical complexity, they are equivalent.

For anyone to say with confidence that the optimization you propose is effective, you need to first study the specific language and platform the code will run on. Most compilers will do tricks for you, different cache configurations can effect [memory locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) (important here for the arrays), etc. Other compilers and interpreters will not.

Additionally, the characteristics of the data also impact effectivity of optimizations. To optimize, you must take sample workloads and compare the optimization's performance against baseline.